# ionic.bundle.js break down into separate imports

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

We are gradually rewriting mobile html5 with Angular.js into Ionic framework. So we have got dozens of functions calling angular.js directly.

Ionic provides a bundle, which combined angular and ionic. We don't want use this bundled one.

As the Ionic CDN docs stated, http://code.ionicframework.com/, we can break down the bundle into separated files.

But no luck to get this work. I tried this on Ionic codepen demos, http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tfAzj

i.e. I replaced

```
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

by using:

```
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>

<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.js"></script>
```

how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: If the js import sequence is correct, i.e. : 1) angular.js, 2) ionic.js, 3) ionic-angular.js. Here for debug purpose, we should not use angular.min.js. Chrome console will print out errors telling us: there are other angular modules are needed, such as: angular-animate, angular-sanitize and angular-ui-router. Is this the only way to breakdown the ionic.bundle.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
```

The order is important. You need all of those libraries, so add them if necessary.